# rbash: Restrict shell commands and functions from profile

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a restricted bash for an user and allowed it only two commands: `sudo` and `passwd`.

`.bash_profile` contains the path to only those two commands: `PATH=$HOME/programs`

However when I login to that user and do <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, it shows some commands as below.

[image]

Some are shell commands and `go` is a function coming from my `/etc/profile`.

How to block all these commands other than the two allowed?

Comment: This question has been answered before, for example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540540/how-do-i-prevent-bash-to-use-a-builtin-command. In short, executing `enable -n <command>` on all the built-in commands should disable them.

Comment: Thanks. Few of them I disabled using `enable -n`. Including `enable` itself.